# Syntax error #1064

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

this is my query:

```
update `zen_meta_tags_products_description` 
set `metatags_keywords`= 'ice machine, ice maker, ice flaker, Brema,'
WHERE `products_id` = ('1231'; '1232'; '1233'; '1234'; '1235'; '1236'; '1237'; '1238'; '1239'; '1240';)
```

Error

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1232, 1233' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove semicolom from your list

Insted of = use IN to get write result:

```
UPDATE `zen_meta_tags_products_description` 
set `metatags_keywords`= 'ice machine, ice maker, ice flaker, Brema,'
WHERE `products_id` IN ('1231', '1232', '1233','1234', '1235', '1236', '1237', '1238', '1239', '1240') ;
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `=` to compare multiple values. You need to use `IN()`. The separator for values in `IN()` is a comma, not a semi colon. The last one is also not necessary and will cause an error. The quotes around the IDs are also not necessary unless you actually did store them as strings.

```
update zen_meta_tags_products_description 
set metatags_keywords= 'ice machine, ice maker, ice flaker, Brema,' 
WHERE products_id IN(1231, 1232, 1233, 1234, 1235, 1236, 1237, 1238, 1239, 1240)
```

Comment: the tables needs this quotation marks as well, but it worked :)